# Pandas try to append a row to a dataframe but keeps overwriting the existing row

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe (df_UP) looks like this:

```
        Total_trends    #up  #down  #flat
    0.05    811         326   310    175
```

I am using a jupyter notebook, when I try to append a row with the following code:

```
`d = {'Total_trends': [total.time], '#up': [good_trigger.time], '#down': [bad_trigger.time], '#flat': [flat.time]}
df_UP.append(d, ignore_index=True)`
```

It works the first time:

```
Total_trends    #up #down   #flat
0   811 326 310 175
1   [811]   [326]   [310]   [175]
```

But when I run again the cell with other values in `d`, it just overwrites the existing data at row 1 with the new one, any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: For me it working perfectly, maybe need `df_UP = df_UP.append(pd.DataFrame(d), ignore_index=True)` ?

Comment: @jezrael, yup the following: `df_UP = df_UP.append(pd.DataFrame(d), ignore_index=True)` works! you can add it as answer, I will validate it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert dictionary to `DataFrame` and assign back:

```
d = {'Total_trends': [10], '#up': [20], '#down': [3], '#flat': [0]}

df_UP = df_UP.append(pd.DataFrame(d), ignore_index=True)
print (df_UP)
   Total_trends  #up  #down  #flat
0           811  326    310    175
1            10   20      3      0

d = {'Total_trends': [160], '#up': [270], '#down': [63], '#flat': [30]}
df_UP = df_UP.append(pd.DataFrame(d), ignore_index=True)
print (df_UP)

   Total_trends  #up  #down  #flat
0           811  326    310    175
1            10   20      3      0
2           160  270     63     30
```